# Powershell leaving RemoteDrive Sessions open

Tags: powershell, windows-share

***Minimal Question:***

How do I properly dispose of the remote Session Connection left behind after doing:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $VM -Credential $CurrentUser
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    $drive = New-PSDrive -Credential $Using:CurrentUser "dummyDriveName" -Root (Split-Path $Using:TargetPath) -PSProvider "FileSystem" 
    Set-Location $Using:TargetPath
}

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
    Remove-PSDrive "dummyDriveName"
}
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
```

---

I'm running code that looks roughly like this:

```
$VMs = @(
    "vm1.foo.lan",
    "vm2.foo.lan",
    "vm3.foo.lan"
)

$TargetPath = "\\$env:ComputerName\bar\bin\Debug"

$CurrentUser = (Get-Credential -Credential $env:UserName)
[System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSession[]]$Sessions = @()

foreach ($VM in $VMs) {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $VM -Credential $CurrentUser
    $Sessions = $Sessions + $session

    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        $drive = New-PSDrive -Credential $Using:CurrentUser "dummyDriveName" -Root (Split-Path $Using:TargetPath) -PSProvider "FileSystem" 
        Set-Location $Using:TargetPath
        #Actually do something here, but it's not relevant ... I can reproduce with this line commented out.
    }
}

# Wait until Target.exe are known to be complete.

foreach ($session in $Sessions) {
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        Remove-PSDrive "dummyDriveName"
    }
    Remove-PSSession -Session $session
}
```

My intent is to get a set of remote machines to all invoke an `exe` sitting on my machine, exposed via a remote share.

Broadly speaking, I:

- Connect to the remote machine as myself.
- Capture that connection.
- Set up a remote drive connecting it to me

  - (This is REQUIRED to avoid the double hop issue without resorting to `CredSsp` See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/setup/ps-remoting-second-hop)
- Do some stuff
- Repeat for all machines.
- Wait until remote processes are completed.
- Reconnect to all the machines to remove the drive and the connection session.

At the end of this, I still have:
[image]

These sessions do eventually seem to decay, but not reliably, and it's been able to saturate the max # sessions allowed and thus cause errors saying:

```
No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (dummy:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
+ PSComputerName        : build7.foo.lan
```

---

***UPDATE:***

Thanks to @jrider who has suggested `Get-SmbSession`.
Running that after the rest of my script returns:

```
PS C:\WorkingDirectoty> Get-SmbSession

SessionId    ClientComputerName ClientUserName NumOpens
---------    ------------------ -------------- --------
773228331225 10.xxx.yyy.89       FOO\MDM        785
773228331233 10.xxx.yyy.60       FOO\MDM        637
773228331245 10.xxx.yyy.89       FOO\MDM        239
773228331253 10.xxx.yyy.54       FOO\MDM        136
773228331261 10.xxx.yyy.54       FOO\MDM        882
773228331269 10.xxx.yyy.60       FOO\MDM        389
```

I obviously don't want this script to blindly close EVERY session irrespective of whether it relates to this script, so I guess I want to map my sessions to IP addresses and close anything with that IP address?
Does anyone JustKnow the necessary PowerShell incantation to achieve that?

Comment: Could you use `Copy-Item -ToSession` to copy the exe to the remote machines and run from there (deleting afterwards, if necessary)?  No need to connect back, etc.

Comment: To your question, "How do I properly dispose of the remote Session Connection left behind after doing..." You have it. ```Remove-PSSession```.

Comment: @LordAdam well evidently not, since those sessions are still present after doing that!

Comment: @boxdog good thought, but unfortunately not an option due to the nature of Target.exe

Comment: @Brondahl have you tried using `Exit-PSSession` before removing ? Don't know if that would make a difference

Comment: @jrider Interesting idea, will try .... Answer: no joy :(

Comment: @Brondahl How about `Get-SmbSession | Close-SmbSession -Force '

Comment: @jrider Ah hah! Progress ... see imminent update

Comment: @Brondahl, the smb session not the ps session. Gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Close the SMB sessions by computer name(Updated to include Brondahl's suggestion):

```
$vmName = $env:ComputerName
$IP =  [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($vmName).IPAddressToString
Get-SmbSession | Where-Object {$_.ClientComputerName -eq $IP} | Close-SmbSession -Force
```

Comment: Could you add `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($vmName).IPAddressToString` to get the whole thing (source: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2006/06/26/windows-powershell-one-liner-name-to-ip-address/)

Answer (score 1):

For final reference, my complete cleanup code looks like this:

```
foreach ($session in $Sessions) {
    Write-Host ""
    $vmName = $session.ComputerName
    $vmIPAddress = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($vmName).IPAddressToString

    Write-Host "*** Killing any active Target.exe processes on $vmName ***"
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        Stop-Process -Name "Target" -Force
    }

    Write-Host "*** Disconnecting the remote Drive created to give $vmName easy access to $RepositoryShare***"
    Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
        Remove-PSDrive "dummyDriveName" 
    }

    Write-Host "*** Closing any open PS connections to $vmName ***"
    Remove-PSSession -Session $session

    Write-Host "*** Closing the still-open Windows Share connection from $vmName to $env.ComputerName ***"
    Get-SmbSession | Where-Object {$_.ClientComputerName -eq $vmIPAddress} | Close-SmbSession -Force
}
```